# Getting an Annotations\DocLexer Syntax error with my Doctrine Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Having some troubles with Symfony 2.

Trying to get some rows from table with my entity.

Here is the Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string" name="title")
     */
    protected $title;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int" name="author_id")
     */
    protected $authorId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime" name="creation_date")
     */
    protected $creationDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="string")
     */
    protected $content;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getAuthorId()
    {
        return $this->authorId;
    }

    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

the Controller

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Article a'
        );

        $article = $query->getResult();
```

Getting Error

> [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'name' at position 26 in property AppBundle\Entity\Article::$title.

I do not have anything on line 26.
Anybody can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You have annotation, it isn't nothing. After you correct your code as @Drick512 suggested, you will have that message on 32 and later on 37 line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is all but explicit...

I think you should just have a comma:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="title")
 */
protected $title;
```

BTW, `name` is not useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Those atributes should be separated by comma. And you should use name only if variable you use is differ from column name. For example, you have some_var in DB, but must use $someVar in code.